# Плагин для отправки письма с сайта wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как можно написать плагин отправки пиьсма с сайта wordpress? Уже 3 день делаю просто через php, все неудачно, никакие гайды не помогли, ни при настройке php.ini sendmail.ini, phpmailer, но в wordpress все равно другая система, как должен выглядеть плагин?

Comment: используйте готовое решение, полно плагинов для создания форм.
либо смотрите в сторону этой функции https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail

Comment: Не надо велосипедить. Есть масса плагиноа для отправки писем из WP. Лучший из них WP Mail SMTP https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: Задача просто была сделать самому, простой код для отправки письма с сайта на почту

Comment: Если по каким-то причинам нужно самому, то изучите парочку статей, отправка письма [wp_mail()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail), а если нужно прям отдельный плагин, то инфы тоже навалом [например](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/plugin/osnovy)

Comment: Лучший - CF7 ;)

Comment: "Простые коды" остались в прошлом веке.

Comment: А такой вопрос, если сайт на локальном сервере xampp расположен, сообщения могут отправляться на почту или нет?